# Rotas - Angular 2

Tags: angular-routes, angular

Vou usar um exemplo de um painel de admin.

No angular 1 eu tinha o `$stateProvider.state()` que dentro dele eu conseguia configurar um nome interno e a url que seria acessado, assim eu teria, por exemplo:

```
.state('template', {
    url: '',
    abstract: true,
    views: {
        'main': {
            templateUrl: 'template/layout.html'
        }
    }
})
.state('template.Parceiro', {
    url: '/Parceiro',
    views: {
        'content': {
            templateUrl: MakeUrl('view/Parceiro/index.html'),
            controller: 'ParceiroController as vm'                        
        }
    }
})
```

Então eu tenho um template padrão que vai ser carregado dentro da tag 'main' quando eu acessar #/Parceiro... Primeiro então eu vou carregar o caminho 'template' que pode ter lá dentro meu menu, rodapé, etc e dentro desse 'template' tenho uma tag 'content' que vai carregar o conteúdo de fato da minha requisição '/Parceiro'.

Porque isso? Para quando eu acessar o /Login que é:

```
.state('Login', {
    ​url: '/Login',
    ​views: {
        ​'main': {
            ​templateUrl: MakeUrl('view/Login/index.html'),
            ​controller: 'LoginController as vm',
        ​}
​    }
​})
```

​Ele irá carregar a página de login na tag 'main' que tem só um form no lugar de todo o meu template carregado anteriormente, sendo assim não terá nada de menu, rodapé, que faz parte do meu layout do painel de admin.
Ai quando eu fizer o login ele redirecionará para /Parceiro que irá carregar novamente template no lugar da tag 'main' e depois o conteúdo do request de /Parceiro na tag 'content'.

Como faço este mesmo jeito, só com com o angular 2?

Obrigado.

(Tela de login)
[image: Tela de login]

(Tela de admin de parceiros)
[image: Tela de admin de parceiros]

Comment: Procurando mais na internet, encontrei o https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/ Que mais em exemplos, ele faz a mesma coisa que fazia no angular 1 (https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/tutorial/hellogalaxy#views)